# Oracle Sql 3 tables with count condition and equal condition

Tags: sql, oracle, count

```
CREATE TABLE    CUSTOMER (
CUSID   VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
CNAME   VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (CUSID),
);

CREATE TABLE    SHOP (
SHOPID  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS VARCHAR(25),
CONSTRAINT SHOP_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (SHOPID),
);

CREATE TABLE    VISIT (
CUSID   VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
SHOPID  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
VDATE   DATE        NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT VISIT_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (CUSID, SHOPID, VDATE),
CONSTRAINT VISIT_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY (CUSID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSID),
CONSTRAINT VISIT_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY (SHOPID) REFERENCES SHOP(SHOPID)
);
```

how to find the address of shops that have been visited at least 2 times by customer with name 'john'??

SELECT ADDRESS FROM SHOP NATURAL JOIN VISIT WHERE CUSID IN (SELECT CUSID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CNAME = 'john' GROUP BY CUSID HAVING COUNT(CUSID) > 2);

i have tried many kinds of joins, it seems that after i put count and equal condition in together,my results will be 0 rows.

Comment: hint JOIN the tables and user the WHERE clause to restrict the rows

Comment: The purpose of SO is to establish a repository of answers to  *programming* questions which will be of interest to other people.  It is not a homework by proxy service.

Comment: SELECT ADDRESS FROM SHOP NATURAL JOIN VISIT WHERE CUSID IN (SELECT CUSID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CNAME = 'john' GROUP BY CUSID HAVING COUNT(CUSID) > 2);

Comment: Do not use natural joins, those can be treacherous :) Use regular JOIN instead.

Comment: tried join,and sub-query...but no idea how to use outer join,i not sure if i need it for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT s.address
    FROM shop s 
    JOIN visit v ON s.shopid = v.shopid 
    JOIN customer c ON v.customerid = c.customerid 
    WHERE c.cname = 'John' 
    GROUP BY 
    s.address
    , c.customerid 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot...mess up my group by and having logic...make a lot of mistake there.

Comment: I added a small correction so the query doesn't return duplicate shop names